# Java 8 Files.walk not returning all Paths

Tags: java-8, nio

Here is the method

```
public List<Path> listAllPaths() throws IOException {
         Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp")).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.toString()));
        return Files.walk(Paths.get(filePath)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

when I execute this method, I see only /tmp printed and returned
I was hoping to see all subdirectories and files inside

Javadocs says

"Return a Stream that is lazily populated with Path by walking the file tree rooted at a given starting file. The file tree is traversed depth-first, the elements in the stream are Path objects that are obtained as if by resolving the relative path against start."

Comment: Sure there's stuff in `/tmp`? You have permission to read things in there?

Comment: @brainstorm try `/private/tmp` may be? (in case you are on mac)

Comment: I have contents in /tmp on mac. I can do `ls /tmp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a symbolic link, not a *real* path:

```
Path p = Paths.get("/tmp");
System.out.println(Files.isSymbolicLink(p)); // returns true
```

The real path is `/private/tmp`

you can do an

```
ls -l
```

and see that some of the folders are owned by **_mbsetupuser** user.

Also you can walk the symbolic links as suggest in the comments via:

```
 Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
```

Comment: Ah ha, good spot. Might worth mentioning [`FileVisitOptions.FOLLOW_LINKS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitOption.html#FOLLOW_LINKS).

Comment: yes. it works. but unfortunately, one of the file /tmp/cvcd results in AccessDeniedException so I get no list returned.